# pdfTex error: invalid font identifier. Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontspec, font-encodings, r

I am using the LawTeX template: [LawTeX](https://github.com/tdannecy/LawTeX). When I try to compile the PDF, I get a pdfTeX error:

invalid font identifier.  *Font T1/pnc/m/n/10-pncr8t at 10.Opt not loadable:  Metric (TFM) file not found*.   LaTeX Font Info:

**Document Log:**
Trying to load font information for T1+pnc on input line 112.
(c:/Users/Robert/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1pnc.fd
File: t1pnc.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/pnc.
)
! Font T1/pnc/m/n/10=pncr8t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

relax
l.112 ...\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font='.

**I ran the following parse_packages function:**

```
tinytex::parse_packages(text = "! Font T1/pnc/m/n/10=pncr8t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.")
tlmgr search --file --global "/pncr8t(-(Bold|Italic|Regular).*)?[.](tfm|afm|mf|otf|ttf)"
```

[1](https://github.com/tdannecy/LawTeX) "ncntrsbk"

**I confirmed that ncntrsbk is installed.**
**I confirmed that the ec package is installed.**

I added what I thought was a [TFM file](https://github.com/chiamingyen/extensions/blob/master/extensions/portableLatex/MiKTeX/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/public/esint/esint10.tfm) to the directory containing the .tex file.  There was no change in the error message.

**Question:  How do I install the correct Metric (TFM) file, or substitute the font so the PDF will compile? Or, even better, find a Wizard to fix it.  My searches for Wizards TFtoPL/PLtoTF (whatever those are) were not successful.**

**Thank you.**

Comment: You need the tfm. Where exactly is `pncr8t.tfm` in your system?

Comment: Thank you for your question.    That file lives in two places:  (1) C:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\fonts\tfm\adobe\ncntrsbk    and      (2) C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts\tfm\adobe\ncntrsbk

Comment: that doesn't sound like one of the trees of your tinytex. You seem to have three tex systems (texlive 2022, tinytex and miktex) and two of them have your font.

Comment: Thank you.  I no longer get the error after moving the pncr8t.tfm to the C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\tex\latex\psnfss\pncr8t.tfm    Thank you.